# Modifing an item of a listView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

i am finishing the application that i am making with a friend, but i have a problem when the listview display the associates of the club it gives you the option for each one of them to edit or modify the information in their profile. I want to know how can i do that? And if its necessary to go to the same layout in whiche they where created to modify them?

(Sorry for that, there is the code for the listView)

AltaSocio.java

```
package com.example.polideportivo1;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;



public class AltaSocio extends Activity {
    Socios nuevosSocio = new Socios(0,"","","","","","","","",0,0,"");
    private EditText editDocumento;
    private EditText editApellido;
    private EditText editNombre;
    private CheckBox checkBoxM;
    private CheckBox checkBoxF;
    private EditText editCivil;
    private Spinner Nacionalidad;
    private EditText Nacimiento;
    private EditText Domicilio;
    private Spinner Localidad;
    private EditText Celular;
    private EditText TelFijo;
    private EditText Correo;
    String miNacionalidad;
    String miLocalidad;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alta_socio2);

        editDocumento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDocumento);
        editApellido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editApellido);
        editNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNombre);
        editCivil = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCivil);
        Nacimiento = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNacimiento);
        Domicilio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDomicilio);
        Celular = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCelular);
        TelFijo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editFijo);
        Correo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCorreo);
        checkBoxM = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkM);
        checkBoxF = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkF);
        Nacionalidad = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerNacionalidad);
        Localidad = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocalidad);

        final Button BtnCrear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonCrear);
        final Button BtnCerrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAtras);



        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Nacionalidad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        Nacionalidad.setAdapter(adapter);

        Nacionalidad.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener () {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                miNacionalidad = Nacionalidad.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //another call

            }

        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Localidad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        Localidad.setAdapter(adapter2);

        Localidad.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener () {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                miLocalidad = Localidad.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                //another call

            }
        });




    }

    public void grabar(View v) {
        nuevosSocio.setCI(Integer.parseInt(editDocumento.getText().toString()));
        nuevosSocio.setApellido(editApellido.getText().toString());
        nuevosSocio.setNombre(editNombre.getText().toString());
        nuevosSocio.setEstadoCivil(editCivil.getText().toString());

        DateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateFormat DataSocio;

        try {
            String Fecha =(Nacimiento.getText().toString());
            formateador.parse(Fecha);
            nuevosSocio.setFechaNacimiento(Fecha);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) 
            {
            Toast g = Toast.makeText(this, "Formato Fecha no valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            }
        nuevosSocio.setDomicilio(Domicilio.getText().toString());
        nuevosSocio.setTelefonoCelular(Integer.parseInt(Celular.getText().toString()));
        nuevosSocio.setTelefonoFijo(Integer.parseInt(TelFijo.getText().toString()));
        nuevosSocio.setCorreo(Correo.getText().toString());
        if (checkBoxM.isChecked()) {
            nuevosSocio.setSexo("Masculino");
        } else {
            nuevosSocio.setSexo("Femenino");
        }
        nuevosSocio.setNacionalidad(miNacionalidad);
        nuevosSocio.setLocalidad(miLocalidad);



        VariablesGlobales.getInstance().getSocios().add(nuevosSocio);
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Los datos fueron grabados",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
        finish();
    }



}
```

alta_socio2.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTituloAlta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/TituloAlta"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDocumento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textMenuAlta"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/IdDocumento" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editDocumento"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/IdNombre" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMenuAlta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTituloAlta"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/MenuAlta" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editApellido"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editNombre"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editDocumento"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editNombre"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/IdApellido" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editApellido"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/IdSexo" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textSexo"
        android:text="@string/IdSM" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkM"
        android:text="@string/IdSF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCivil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editApellido"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/IdEstadoCivil" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerNacionalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkF"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editCivil"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCivil"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editNacimiento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDomicilio"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerNacionalidad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerNacionalidad"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:text="@string/IdFechaNacimiento" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editDomicilio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editNacimiento"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/IdDomicilio"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLocalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerNacionalidad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editDomicilio"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNacionalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editCivil"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerNacionalidad"
        android:text="@string/IdNacionalidad" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLocalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDomicilio"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerLocalidad"
        android:text="@string/IdLocalidad" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCelular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerLocalidad"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:text="@string/IdTelefonoCelular" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFijo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCelular"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:text="@string/IdTelefonoFijo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCorreo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editFijo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerLocalidad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editFijo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text="@string/IdDireccionCorreo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCorreo"
        android:text="@string/IdFoto"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCorreo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/botonImagen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textFoto"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botonImagen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editCorreo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editCorreo"
        android:text="@string/BotonImagen" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/botonAtras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/botonImagen"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/botonImagen"
        android:text="@string/BotonFichaAtras"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/botonCrear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/botonImagen"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textFoto"
        android:text="@string/BotonCrear"
        android:onClick="grabar"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

lista_socio_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TituloSocio"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/TituloSocio"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/ListaMainSocio"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TituloSocio"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

lista_socio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/IdNombre"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textApellido"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNombre"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdApellido"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#99CC"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#99CC"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textApellido"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdDocumento"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textCI"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdSexo"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEstadoCivil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textSexo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdEstadoCivil"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNacionalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEstadoCivil"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdNacionalidad"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNacimiento"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNacionalidad"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdFechaNacimiento"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDomicilio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textNacimiento"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdDomicilio"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLocalidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textDomicilio"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdLocalidad"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTelFijo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textLocalidad"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdTelefonoFijo"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTelCel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTelFijo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdTelefonoCelular"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCorreo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTelCel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/IdDireccionCorreo"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

ArrayAdapterSocio.java

```
package com.example.polideportivo1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArrayAdapterSocio extends ArrayAdapter<Socios>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Socios>socio = VariablesGlobales.getInstance().getSocios();

    public ArrayAdapterSocio(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Socios> soc) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, soc);
        this.context= context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.socio = soc;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;
        CapturadorSocio CapturadorSocio = null;

        if (item == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            CapturadorSocio = new CapturadorSocio();
            CapturadorSocio.nombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
            CapturadorSocio.apellido = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textApellido);
            CapturadorSocio.documento = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textCI);
            CapturadorSocio.sexo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textSexo);
            CapturadorSocio.estadoCivil = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textEstadoCivil);
            CapturadorSocio.nacionalidad = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textNacionalidad);
            CapturadorSocio.fechaNacimiento = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textNacimiento);
            CapturadorSocio.domicilio = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textDomicilio);
            CapturadorSocio.localidad = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textLocalidad);
            CapturadorSocio.telfijo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textTelFijo);
            CapturadorSocio.telcelular = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textTelCel);
            CapturadorSocio.correo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textCorreo);
            CapturadorSocio.edit = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
            CapturadorSocio.delete = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            item.setTag(CapturadorSocio);
        } else {
            CapturadorSocio = (CapturadorSocio) item.getTag();
        }

        Socios socios = socio.get(position);
        CapturadorSocio.nombre.setText(socios.obtenerNombre());
        CapturadorSocio.apellido.setText(socios.obtenerApellido());
        //CapturadorSocio.documento.setText(socios.obtenerCI());
        CapturadorSocio.sexo.setText(socios.obtenerSexo());
        CapturadorSocio.estadoCivil.setText(socios.obtenerEstadoCivil());
        CapturadorSocio.nacionalidad.setText(socios.obtenerNacionalidad());
        CapturadorSocio.fechaNacimiento.setText(socios.obtenerFechaNacimiento());
        CapturadorSocio.domicilio.setText(socios.obtenerDomicilio());
        CapturadorSocio.localidad.setText(socios.obtenerLocalidad());
        CapturadorSocio.telfijo.setText(socios.obtenerTelefonoFijo());
        CapturadorSocio.telcelular.setText(socios.obtenerCelular());
        CapturadorSocio.correo.setText(socios.obtenerCorreo());


        return item;

    }





    static class CapturadorSocio {
        TextView nombre;
        TextView apellido;
        TextView documento;
        TextView sexo;
        TextView estadoCivil;
        TextView nacionalidad;
        TextView fechaNacimiento;
        TextView domicilio ;
        TextView localidad;
        TextView telfijo;
        TextView telcelular;
        TextView correo;
        Button edit;
        Button delete;
    }
}
```

ListarSocio.java

```
package com.example.polideportivo1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListarSocio extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    ArrayAdapterSocio socioArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Socios>socio = VariablesGlobales.getInstance().getSocios();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_socio_main);

        socioArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterSocio(ListarSocio.this, R.layout.list_socio, socio);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListaMainSocio);
        listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listview.setAdapter(socioArrayAdapter);
    }



}
```

Comment: I couldn't find a ListView in your code ... Are you talking about one of your Spinners ?

Comment: i am sorry, it is there now.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer for handling click events on specific widgets inside your ListView items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your ArrayAdapterSocio.java implement View.OnClickListener, so you would define your class like this :

```
public class ArrayAdapterSocio extends ArrayAdapter<Socios> implements View.OnClickListener{

    // Your previous code

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Your previous code
        CapturadorSocio.edit.setTag(socios.obtenerId); 
        // Hopefully you have a method to identify your memebers by Id. 
        // Otherwise, use another unique identifier, like their name.
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnEdit:
            // The edit button was clicked, launch your edition here.
            // You can get the Id of the member by calling v.getTag(),
            // use that to launch edition on the correct member.
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can reuse your member creation layout and even activity/fragment, but you don't have to. Espero haber ayudado ;)

Comment: Thanks its very helpful.Yes, by the documento or CI i can identify them. One question in the onClick i have to make an intent that goes to the AltoSocio.java to edit him? if the ansewer is yes, how can I in the AltoSocio get that intent so i don´t normally go to the create user. (Mas facil en español jaja, como hago para que el AltoSocio se inicie desde ahi y no me cree un usuario nuevo?).

Comment: Si no le importa, seguimos en ingles asi los demas tambien podran aprovechar de la respuesta ;) Podrias acceptar la respuesta si responde a su pregunta? Gracias !

Comment: To pass data between Activities, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. Then at the start of your AltaSocio.java, check if Intent is provided by doing if (getIntent.getString(EXTRA_NAME) != null), and fill the data in layout widgets if it is. Your save function should edit existing records if Intent exists.

Comment: Thanks you very much!!!, now that i have all the info i wll try to make it work.